# fill every row of a DataFrame with a single list pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a list where

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I'm trying to create a df of len(list) column where every index of df is equal to list

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1  1    2    3    4     5
2  1    2    3    4     5
3  1    2    3    4     5
```

I supose this is pretty easy but I can't find it. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> pd.DataFrame([my_list], index=range(5), 
                 columns=['col{0}'.format(n) for n in range(1, len(my_list) + 1)])
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     2     3     4     5
1     1     2     3     4     5
2     1     2     3     4     5
3     1     2     3     4     5
4     1     2     3     4     5
```